# Why is "or" appropriate?

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence " He didn't have his father, mother and wife.".

And the sentence is corrected to "He didn't have his Father, Mother or his wife." by a native speaker.

I wanted to say "He didn't have his father and mother. He didn't also have his wife.", that is he didn't have all them. Why is "or"?

Comment: I think this needs a phrase added to make sense, because you can't just say "He didn't have his father..." since everyone has or had one. If you mean "didn't have them do something" then you need to add the *something*. I guess I am saying that you need to complete the thought. Also I disagree on the capitalization change (AmE), though this may be a regional thing.

Answer (score 1):

The native speaker is correct.  "He didn't have his father, mother or wife" is the right way to say that he lacked all three.

(The apparent change in capitalisation isn't really desirable, though, and the extra "his" before "wife" is unnecessary, although harmless.)

Did he have his father, mother or wife?  No, he didn't have his father, mother or wife.  I don't think anyone would interpret the "or" to mean that he might not lack all of them.  You could write "he had neither his father, his mother nor his wife", but in practice you wouldn't worry about the "or" being ambiguous (unless perhaps you were drawing up a legally binding document or the like).

We wouldn't normally say "he didn't have his father, mother and wife".  It makes it sound as though the three people constitute a unit or close-knit grouping.  It would tend to suggest that all three of them lived with him or were typically found in the same place as him.